# Generate separate plots of coordinates by ID column in DataFrame with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame with ID's and an x and y value. I need need to plot the x and y coordinates for each ID on a separate graph.

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B','B','A','C','C'], 'X': [5,3,4,2,5,3], 'Y':[1,2,6,4,5,2]})
```

For this example data, the expected result would be 3 graphs (A,B and C) each with two points plotted. The code I have tried follows:

```
   groups = df.groupby('ID')
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   for ID,group in groups:
        ax.plot(group.X,group.Y)
```

This separates the points by ID, but plots everything on the same graph. How can I generate separate graphs for each ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you plot everything into `ax`. Do instead:

```
groups = df.groupby('ID')

# this is not needed
# fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for ID,group in groups:
    group.plot(x='X',y='Y')
```

Comment: I like this one better because then you can easily add `label=ID` to the plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly with

```
df.groupby('ID').plot(x='X', y='Y')
```

this will create a graph per ID